# Show list of categories in post editor only from current custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

How to show list of categories in post editor (admin area) only from current custom post type?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-taxonomies-admin-columns-filters-and-archives/) & [this](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/innovative-uses-of-wordpress-post-types-and-taxonomies/) are a subset of good resources for taxonomies/categories for custom post types available online. Hope they are helpful.